# How to correctly call the .NET logger.LogError method with 2x params?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to do a call to this `logger.LogError` method but the wrong extension method keeps getting called.

I have:

```
_logger.LogError("This is an error {someBool} and {someString}", someBool, someString);
```

and it's calling this extension method:

[image]

but I'm wanting to call this extension method instead:

[image]

How do I end up calling -that- specific extension method?

UPDATE:

As suggested below, hit `F12` to goto the code ... and it is this (keep reading afterwards .. there's a catch!)

[image]

So *at first* that namespace *looks like* it's official ..

until I noticed the ASSEMBLY it's part of and stuff .. and it's all a custom class in a private nuget package (for this company) from another dev. CHEEKY!!!!!

So yeah - it's all a custom extension method.

I thought it was part of the *official* MS code. I appologize.

Comment: That extension method (`LogError(string, object, string)`) doesn't look like it is "official". At least it does not exist in [here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs,c04734fc35ce2b66). Maybe it is some custom method you (accidentally) included? Use "Go to definition" (F12) to find out where it comes from. To answer your final question: you could do `_logger.LogError("...", new object[] { someBool, someString })`, but I would try to find out where that other method comes from.

Comment: Roblox's OOOF. yeppers. Upon closer inspection, this is actually some _custom code_ in the company. Eeks. Sorry. I've updated the O.P. with the new details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always *force* the compiler by using the exact types required for one of the functions, if you don't like the automatic resolution:

```
_logger.LogError("This is an error {someBool} and {someString}", 
                 new object[] { someBool, someString });
```

That said, I never had this problem, check where this method comes from and why it gets picked over the one you prefer.

Since the method you want comes from a class the other method is not defined in, you could also call it directly, without the extension method syntax:

```
LoggerExtensions.LogError(
       _logger,
       "This is an error {someBool} and {someString}", 
       someBool, 
       someString);
```

This should rule out those other method that conflicts with what you want.

Comment: Cheers mate! Appreciate the details answer and help 

Answer (score 1):

To use the extension method you need to pass an object array.

Try to do something like:

```
object[] params = {var1, var2, var3};
```